# Mysql sort alphanumeric data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `tt1` and `tt2` both contains same fields. I want to sort data by `no` from both table.

Table : **tt1**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tt1` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `no` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `tt1` (`id`, `no`) VALUES
(1, '1A'),
(2, '3A'),
(3, '2A');
```

Table : **tt2**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tt2` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `no` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
INSERT INTO `tt2` (`id`, `no`) VALUES
(1, '2A'),
(2, '3A'),
(3, '1A');
```

**Expected output**

```
ID | No
========
1  | 1A
3  | 1A
1  | 2A
3  | 2A
2  | 3A
2  | 3A
```

I want to ascending order of `no` field from both table as given output how I can get.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95546/1)

Comment: See the updated sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95546/5

Comment: @Ullas It returns total 5 rows actually there is 6 rows

Comment: UNION selects only distinct values. Second row of both the tables are same.

Comment: @Ullas I think you have to write `union all` instead of `union`

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` to select all values. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95546/18

Comment: Yaa you are right @Sadikhasan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case using `order by` after every `select` is wrong (won't return desired output), because that will order both row-sets separately and union them after that.

What you want here is to order already combined data, therefore you should be using `order by` only once, after mysql makes union of tables (i.e. combines), because once it combines tables it has all data together but unordered, so when mysql sees `order by` it orders whole data for you.

Sample:

```
select * from `tt1`
union all
select * from `tt2`
order by `no`
```

**Note:** I've noticed you have wrong syntax in your fiddle. You need to add parentheses:

```
(select * from tt1 order by no)
union
(select * from tt2 order by no)
```

**Note 2:** Thanks [@AlmaDo's notice](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17600421#17600421). You should not use `*` with `union` queries. Because modification of your tables columns will break query. Use column names that you actually need. E.g. query in sample becomes:

```
select `id`, `no` from `tt1`
union all
select `id`, `no` from `tt2`
order by `no`
```

Comment: It returns total 5 rows actually there is 6 rows in table

Comment: I think you have to write `union all` instead of `union`

Comment: @Sadikhasan That has nothing to do with ordering. That happens because there're exactly same two entries `id=2, no = 3A`, so mysql will return that only once with `union`.

Comment: @Sadikhasan Yes, `union all` will do that. I just copy pasted from your fiddle, so I thought that `union` was expected behavior. Thanks for clarification. ;)